# Site getting down after some time with error code 524/521 VPS is getting hanged

Tags: xampp, virtualhost, connection-timeout

My WordPress website which is running on a TransIP VPS getting down after some time when some visitors access it with error code 524 or 521.
On VPS its running on XAMPP server Apache and PHPMyadmin via virtual host configuration. In VPS and domain for SSL Cloudflare is used. when some users accessed the site within 10-20 mins is getting down with error code 524(timeout) or 521. When I visit VPS console at same time its getting stucked and I'm not able to do anything because of that need to restart the VPS for Restart the site. Please Help me to fix this issue..

Checked the Traceroute for any packet drop but there is no package drop.
checked firewall rules for Ports
Ask Hosting provider they said everything is ok from their side
no issue of space from 150 GB of SSD 130 GB is available